# insert labels in proportional bar chart with ggplot2 and geom_text

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to insert labels into a proportional barchart: one label per segment, with as text the percentage of each segment. With the help of thothal I managed to do this:

```
var1 <- factor(as.character(c(1,1,2,3,1,4,3,2,3,2,1,4,2,3,2,1,4,3,1,2)))
var2 <- factor(as.character(c(1,4,2,3,4,2,1,2,3,4,2,1,1,3,2,1,2,4,3,2)))
data <- data.frame(var1, var2)


dat <- ddply(data, .(var1), function(.) {
res <- cumsum(prop.table(table(factor(.$var2))))
data.frame(lab = names(res), y = c(res))
})

ggplot(data, aes(x = var1)) + geom_bar(aes(fill = var2), position = 'fill') +
geom_text(aes(label = lab, x = var1, y = y), data = dat)
```

I would like to have for labels the percentage of each level, and not the level name.

[image]

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way to get non-cumulative percentage plus centering the labels, for future reference:

```
dat <- ddply(data, .(var1), function(.) {
good <- prop.table(table(factor(.$var2)))
res <- cumsum(prop.table(table(factor(.$var2))))
data.frame(lab = names(res), y = c(res), good = good, pos = cumsum(good) - 0.5*good)
})

ggplot(data, aes(x = var1)) + geom_bar(aes(fill = var2), position = 'fill') +
geom_text(aes(label = round(good.Freq, 2), x = var1, y = pos.Freq), data = dat)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You are telling `geom_text` to use `var2` as your `y` variable. That is in fact `as.numeric(data$var2)`, which translates to a range of `1-4`. However, your barplot uses the cumulative percentages.

Hence you have to calculate these positions before:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr) # just for convenience
var1 <- factor(as.character(c(1,1,2,3,1,4,3,2,3,2,1,4,2,3,2,1,4,3,1,2)))
var2 <- factor(as.character(c(1,4,2,3,4,2,1,2,3,4,2,1,1,3,2,1,2,4,3,2)))
data <- data.frame(var1, var2)

dat <- ddply(data, .(var1), function(.) {
    res <- cumsum(prop.table(table(factor(.$var2)))) # re-factor to use only used levels
    res2 <- prop.table(table(factor(.$var2))) # re-factor to use only used levels 
    data.frame(lab = names(res), y = c(res), lab2 = c(res2))
})

ggplot(data, aes(x = var1)) + geom_bar(aes(fill = var2), position = 'fill') +
geom_text(aes(label = round(lab2, 2), x = var1, y = y), data = dat)
```

This places the labs at the end of each bar. If you want to have them slightly offset, you should play arround in the creation of `dat`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help! It works perfectly, but... It's not what I want to do - I have explained it badly. I am editing the question, leaving the part solved and adding a new part: in fact, as labels I would like to have the percentage for each level of var2 and not the level name.

Comment: Well, not so difficult:  just change the `label` argument in `geom_text(.)`: `geom_text(aes(label = round(y, 2), x = var1, y = y), data = dat)`. Maybe then you want to have not the cumulative sum, but the respective percentages, so you should adjust the creation of `dat`.

Comment: This gives me the cumulative percentage... I would like to have the percentage for each segment! I am trying to work it out... :) However thanks again!

Comment: Updated the answer above, to incorporate this bit.

Answer (score 1):

I used the following code and work well for me, give it a try.

```
 geom_text(aes(label = paste(round(dat2$value,0), "%"),
            vjust = ifelse(value >= 0, -0.05, 1.15)
            ),
        size = 4, position = position_stack(vjust=0.5)
        )
```

Basically, you need `label = paste(y value, "%")`. In my code, dat2 is the data file name; value is the Y value in the figure. In this case, I rounded up the number with 0 decimal.Good luck.