# (ggplot) Pecentage labels in stacked barplot with two categorical variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, cumulative-sum, stacked-chart

I am finding it impossible to create the appropriate labels when plotting two categorical variables in a 100% stacked barplot. Consider the code below (fictional dataset that reproduces my problem):

```
data <- data.frame(
  gender=sample(c("M", "F"), 40, replace=TRUE),
  football=sample(c("Yes", "No"), 40, replace=TRUE)
)
```

What I am trying to do is to create a 100% stacked barplot and display labels for each category. I succeeded in creating the plot with the following code (both ways produce the same plot):

```
ggplot(data, aes(gender))+
  geom_bar(aes(fill=football), position="fill")+
  scale_y_continuous(labels=percent)

ggplot(data, aes(gender, ..count..))+
  geom_bar(aes(fill=football), position="fill", stat="count")+
  scale_y_continuous(labels=percent)
```

[Click here to see the graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpGoQ.png)

I understand that to create percentage labels I need first to compute the cumulative sum. However, I do not get to find a way to properly use "cumsum(var)" with a categorical variable. The closest I have got is to the following:

```
ggplot(data, aes(gender))+
  geom_bar(aes(fill=football), position="fill")+
  geom_text(aes(label=(..count../sum(..count..))*100, fill=football), stat="count")+
  scale_y_continuous(labels=percent)
```

But if you reproduce the code above you will see that percentages refer to the total number of observations (and not to the categories within "gender") as well as the Y-axis gets messy. Any help will be truly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: @shayaa Thanks for the heads-up. Should I then reproduce part of the dataset (or a dummy one for this purpose) in a comment? Or delete this question and start a new one? Sorry for the idiocy, I am certainly not use to this website yet.

Comment: Either is fine; whichever you think is most understandable to the reader is probably best.

Comment: Are you trying to do this without make a separate summary table for the labels? (There are many examples of that for this situation, including [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26586876/insert-labels-in-proportional-bar-chart-with-ggplot2-and-geom-text), just pick your favorite data summary method).

Comment: @aosmith Great, thanks for the link! That solved my problem (and more importantly taught me to do what I was looking for!)