# Add labels to plot or percentage to legend in proportional bar plots ggplot 2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following plot from ggplot2

Proportinal Cancer Barplot:

[image]

And as you can see it is not quite clear which spots on the bar represents which cancer. It was created using the following code:

```
print(ggplot(data, aes(x = var1)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill = var2), position = 'fill', color = "black") +
  labs(title= "Distribution of Cancers", x="groups",y = "Percent", fill = "Cancer"))
```

var1 is just a factor vector of "c(group1,group2)" and var2 is which cancer they have. I apologize for not supplying example data, but I am not sure how to recreate this without unmasking the patient information.

I have spent the better part of a few days trying to get something to work. I have also tried reading up on [Add percentage labels to a stacked barplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44724580/add-percentage-labels-to-a-stacked-barplot)
and [insert labels in proportional bar chart with ggplot2 and geom_text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26586876/insert-labels-in-proportional-bar-chart-with-ggplot2-and-geom-text#)

Yet neither have helped me.

I would like to make the plot easier to read by either adding in the cancer labels into the plot or by adding both percentages next to each cancer in the legend (any other suggestion is also welcome).

Thank you

p.s. to add, the groups are quite one sided (5:2) which is why I want to use proportional plots.

EDIT; to make a sample dataframe that is similar to mine, the following code will work

```
set.seed(12345)
data <- data.frame(var1 = factor(as.character(c(sample(c("Group1","Group2"),size = 500, replace = T)))),
  var2 = factor(as.character(c(sample(c("Bladder", "Bone", "Breast", "Brain", "Colon", "Kidney", "Ovary", "Intestine", "Uterus", "Other"),size = 500, replace=T)))))
```

Comment: Providing a minimally reproducible example will improve your chances of receiving a quality solution by up to 1,000%. Is there some way you can de-identify a small subset of fake data to provide the `dput`?

Comment: Matt, I have updated the question to include code that should create a data frame structured like the one I have. I hope it helps

Comment: Not helpful to your question at all, but: if the goal of the visualisation is to compare the proportions between two classes (current x-axis), why not just make a scatterplot with one class on the x-axis and the other on the y-axis?

Comment: @teunbrand That sounds like an interesting idea. I will give it a try. I would still like to try to get the proportional bar plots working though.

Comment: @teunbrand Welcome to the quest to make people aware of scatter plots!

Comment: @tjebo Most underrated plot!

Comment: @teunbrand I tried the scatter plot using proportions as the variables and it looks harder to read. The points anc cancer labels just overlap each other into a jumbled mess.

Thank you for your suggestion though.